# How should I provide a convenience function taking a single element for a base class function taking an array

Tags: c++, inheritance

Say I have a base class declaring a purely virtual function do_sth() taking a vector, but in the deriving classes often only vectors with a single element are used.
Therefore for convenience I want to provide a second version of do_sth() taking a single element. I do not want to implement this second version in every class deriving
from Base, because its purpose is simply to call the version taking a vector. Therefore my idea was to implement it in the base class like so:

```
class Base {
    virtual void do_sth(const std::vector<int>& v) = 0;
    void do_sth(int n) {
        do_sth(std::vector<int>{n});
    }
};

class Derived : public Base {
    void do_sth(const std::vector<int>& v) override {
          //do_sth with v
    }
};
```

However, this way if users of my code want to call the version taking a single element they have to do it through a pointer to the base class, which
is not what I want.

```
Derived* d = new Derived();
Base* b = new Derived();

d->do_sth(5); // compilation fails because Base::do_sth is hidden in Derived
d->do_sth({5}); // obviously works, but does not make use of convenience function

b->do_sth(5); // works, but requires the user to remember using a
              // pointer to base, e.g. he can't write 
              // auto b = make_shared<Derived>(); b->do_sth(5);
d->Base::do_sth(5); // works, but requires the user to remember
                    // to explicitly call the base class function
```

The only other option I know of is to redefine the convenience function in every class deriving from Base like so:

```
void Derived::do_sth(int n) {
    Base::do_sth(n);
}
```

or to put

```
using Base::do_sth
```

inside the deriving classes.
What I do not like about this is that I have to remember to write the redefinition/using statement in every class 
deriving from Base.

Does someone know another possibly better method to achieve the funcionality I am seeking ? Maybe there is another design option I should choose ?

Comment: Make your `do_sth` functions non-virtual, and have a protected virtual `do_sth_impl` function which does the actual work.

Comment: Yes! This totally solves my issue!

Comment: another option would be to use different names, like: `virtual void add_numbers(const std::vector<int>& v) = 0;` and `void add_number(int n)`